# The same object as input and output in Python - good or bad practice?

Tags: python, dictionary, variables, coding-style

I was just wondering if this is an clean way of writing code - if you define the same name of a variable (and precisely for a dictionary) that you use as an input and an output of some function e.g.:

```
my_dic = {}
my_dic = someFunction(my_dic,otherVariables)
**doing other things with my_dic **
```

The function someFunction only is meant to update the dictionary my_dic, so preferably the output should be the input but updated.
Is this a safe way of coding? or would that result in some possible bugs?

Answer (score 2):

This should not result in any bugs in your program if you are just trying to update the dictionary using a function.